# Log file getting created in wrong location with os.path.join

Tags: python

I am trying to create log files under directory `patchsetcreatedlogs` but the log file gets created as `patchsetcreatedlogspatchset_created_hook_log_11122018_114810.txt` with the below code,

I expect the filw `patchset_created_hook_log_11122018_114810.txt` 
to be created under `patchsetcreatedlogs` ,where am I going wrong?

```
import time,os,logging
# setup logging
patchsetcreatedlog = 'patchset_created_hook_log_' + time.strftime("%m%d%Y") + '_' + time.strftime("%H%M%S") + '.txt'
log = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)),'patchsetcreatedlogs' + patchsetcreatedlog)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
#logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logger.setLevel(10)
ch = logging.StreamHandler()
#ch.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
ch.setLevel(10)
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(filename)-15s %(funcName)-20s %(lineno)-5s  %(levelname)-8s: %(message)s', datefmt="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
ch.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(ch)

fh = logging.FileHandler(log, 'w')
fh.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
fh.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(fh)
```

patchsetcreatedlogspatchset_created_hook_log_11122018_114810.txt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not an issue with `os.path.join`, it's just that by doing:

```
'patchsetcreatedlogs' + patchsetcreatedlog
```

you're adding 2 strings instead of passing them in argument of `join` (which can take any number of arguments, not just 2). So no path delimiter is added.

Besides, `os.path.realpath` is not needed here. The path to the module is a simple path or name. So, just remove it.

```
os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)),'patchsetcreatedlogs' + patchsetcreatedlog)
```

should be:

```
os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'patchsetcreatedlogs', patchsetcreatedlog)
```

(if `__file__` is just a filename, `dirname` returns an empty string and `join` ignores it so it still works)